# MDX Difference between dates non null and of the same dimension

Tags: mdx

Hi I need to calculate No. of days between Counts so the dataset is

[count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMSFL.jpg)

I have created a member of the last date, this returns the last date across the whole dataset as a start but not sure how to proceed.  Is it possible to do this in MDX? if so how?

Thank you

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Last date] AS
MAX([Date].[Full Date].[Full Date].MEMBERS,
iif(  [Measures].[Count] = 0,
 null,
    [Date].[Full Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue
     )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example will help. But please note that it will count from the begining of the month. So if there was an order was on 5 may and the last order was on 28 April then the diffrence would be 4 not 7.

```
with member measures.MonthDate as 
[Date].[Day of Month].CurrentMember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED)

member measures.LastOrderDate as 
(max(
FILTER(
[Date].[Day of Month].firstSibling:[Date].[Day of Month].currentmember.lag(1)
,[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 0)
,measures.MonthDate)
)
member measures.DaysToLastOrder as 
(max(
FILTER(
[Date].[Day of Month].firstSibling:[Date].[Day of Month].currentmember
,[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 0)
,measures.MonthDate)
-measures.LastOrderDate
)

select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Order Count],measures.DaysToLastOrder
}
on columns,
nonempty (([Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year],[Date].[Day of Month].[Day of Month]),[Measures].[Internet Order Count])
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Customer].[City].&[London]&[ENG],[Product].[Subcategory].&[1]--,[Date].[Month of Year].&[11]
)
```

[image: results]