# How To Have Recursive sum in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cumulative-sum

I need to have calculated member in mdx to calculate recursive sum
that should summarize itself with the previous member

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following examples. One is for running total the other one is a bit diffrent.

[Cumulative Sum/ Running Total | MDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149709/cumulative-sum-running-total-mdx/54209110#54209110)

[MDX Difference between dates non null and of the same dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011717/mdx-difference-between-dates-non-null-and-of-the-same-dimension/53821561#53821561)